# Web service is called twice

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, alamofire

I have a problem with a webService call.

The problem is that when I call the service, and debug code, and print log in console, I'm sure my webService is only called once (log print once in console), but my request is apparently sent twice to the server and I have duplicate data in the list.

I know that it's not a server-side problem because it only happens on IOS (not Android).

Here is my code for call services:

```
    public class PersistencyManager {
      public func SendPostHttpRequest(baseURL: String, parameter: [String:Any], content: String, closure:@escaping ((_ success:JSON,_ error:NSError?) -> Void)) {
        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        debugPrint("Request parameter ------>",parameter)
        debugPrint(" Service URL -------> \(baseURL)")
        if let url = URL(string: baseURL) {
          var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
          urlRequest.setValue("text/html; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
          urlRequest.setURLEncodedFormData(parameters: parameter)
          manager.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON) :
              debugPrint("get Json response ---> \((JSON)) ")
              closure(JSON,nil)
            case .failure(let error):
              closure(nil,error as NSError)
              debugPrint("get error ---> \((error.localizedDescription)) ")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    class LibraryAPI {

      static let shareInstance : LibraryAPI = { LibraryAPI() }()
      private let persistencyManager : PersistencyManager
      init() {
        persistencyManager = PersistencyManager()
      }
      func GetPostResponse(baseURL : String,parameters:[String:Any],contentType: String,closure:@escaping ((_ success:PersistencyManager.JSON,_ error:NSError?) -> Void))  {
        persistencyManager.SendPostHttpRequest(baseURL: baseURL, parameter: parameters, content: contentType, closure: { success, error in
          closure(success, error)
        })
      }
    }

class TransactionAPI: TransactionProtocol {

 static let shareInstance: TransactionAPI = {TransactionAPI()}()

func AddNewManagerRequest(_ parameter: [String : Any], closure: @escaping (([String : Any]?, NSError?) -> Void)) {

    let url = Constants.BaseURL + Constants.K_NEWREQPORTERAGE
    LibraryAPI.shareInstance.GetPostResponse(baseURL: url, parameters: parameter, contentType: "JSON", closure: {success,error in

      var response: [String:Any]?
      if let json = success as? [String: Any] {
        response = json
      }
      closure(response, error)

    })
  }
}

 class AddNewOrderViewController: MainViewController {
     private func RegisterForNewPorterageRequest() {

        let time = Utilities.shareInstance.GetSystemTime()
        guard let userID = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user_id") as? String else {
          return
        }
        StartActivity(activityColor: Constants.ACTIVITY_COLOR)
        let token = TokenCreator.shareInstance.CreateTokenWithUserID(userID: userID, methodName: Constants.M_NEWREQUESTPORTERAGE)

        request.tok = token
        request.time = time
        request.user_id = userID

        let jsonModel = Utilities.shareInstance.GetJsonForm(objectClass: request)
        TransactionAPI.shareInstance.AddNewManagerRequest(jsonModel, closure: {[weak self] success,error in

          guard let strongSelf = self else{
            return
          }

          if error != nil {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {

              strongSelf.StopActivity()
              strongSelf.CreateCustomTopField(text: Constants.serverError, color: Constants.ERROR_COLOR)
            }
          }
          else {

            if let response = success {
              debugPrint("add request service call once")

              if let status = response["status"] as? String {

                if status == "succ" {
                  OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    strongSelf.presentResultAlert()
                  }
                }else {
                  OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                    strongSelf.StopActivity()
                    strongSelf.CreateCustomTopField(text: Constants.send_data_error, color: Constants.ERROR_COLOR)
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }

        })
      }
    }
```

After adding log to server, I made sure my request was sent twice to server.

All console log print once in console.

I don't know when I call service twice, and why my request was sent twice to the server.

I don't understand how the log be displayed once, but the service has been called twice?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the server is RETURNING the data twice and that is the problem.

Comment: @BooberBunz This does not happen on the Android platform. This problem only exists in the ios . I thought, because I use Singleton, this happens but there is no problem with any service, but only two of the services have this problem.

Comment: I suppose you could use print debugging since you have  4 classes and 4 cascading methods all calling one another in succession... and the weak self / strong self... not sure. :S

Comment: @BooberBunz I've debugged every line and I'm sure all the methods are called in order. In this controller I call three other services to get different data. I think because all of these refer to the same class and use a Singleton LibraryAPI class, or it's repeated in two different thread simultaneously. If you have another way, I would appreciate your review.

Answer (score 1):

It's really confusing, but it works perfectly with this method. 
i have this method in persistencyMangerClass and i using this method instead SendPostHttpRequest.What really is the difference between these two methods. :|

```
public func SendMultiPartRequestWith(baseUrl: String, parameters: [String : Any],closure: @escaping ((_ success:JSON,_ error:NSError? ) -> Void)){
    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 15
    debugPrint(" Service URL -------> \(baseUrl)")
    debugPrint("Request parameter ------>",parameters)

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
      "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    ]
    manager.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
      for (key, value) in parameters {
        if let data = value as? Data {
          let fileName = (key as String) + ".jpg"
          let mimType = (key as String) + "/jpg"
          multipartFormData.append(data, withName: key as String, fileName: fileName, mimeType: mimType)
        }
        else {
          if let v = value as? String {
          multipartFormData.append("\(v)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
          }else {
            multipartFormData.append("".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
          }
        }
      }
    }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: baseUrl, method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in
      switch result{
      case .success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.responseString { response in
          if let err = response.error{
            closure(nil, err as NSError)
            return
          }
          if let JSON = response.result.value {
            closure(JSON, nil)
          }
        }
      case .failure(let error):
        closure(nil, error as NSError)
      }
    }
  }
```